# ConstraintLayout crashes after library upgrade to 1.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I upgraded ConstraintLayout library from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 and I constantly get this on application start:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.motiv.providerRepository.alpha, PID: 22224
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.getTargetWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:1144)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:994)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:803)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1561)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1148)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1638)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1638)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.811 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:898)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2873)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>   10-26 17:21:44.812 22224 22224 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

I cannot see anything in this log because it looks like a system issue.
Also, I don't cast view holders manually like said in a crash report.

I tried to clean, analyze issue, but nothing.

Issue seen on Samsung S8 with 8.0 Android.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Delete your .gradle caches. I had something similar happen to me after I updated a support library a few weeks back and completely deleting all of my .gradle caches helped me, might be worth a shot in your case.

Comment: Try to downgrade it once and see if the problem appears. 
PS : as far as i see, you are making a false casting. Try it with downgrade, if the problem persist send a screenshot of the error or copy-paste a more precise one.

Comment: 1.1.2 works good, so I use it currently. 1.1.3 fails..